# Concatenate name value in Laravel collective form with variable

Tags: laravel-5

I have a bunch of selects I need in my view. 18 of them and want to simply use a for loop to count and make the name of the select

`hole#_gir` where number is a number from 1-18

I have this

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < 18; $i++)
    <td>
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::select('hole1_gir', array(1 => 'Yes', 0 => 'No'), ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
        </div>
    </td>
@endfor
```

Question is can I and how can I do:

`hole . $1 . _gir` in the above Form::select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@for($i=0;$i<18;$i++)
<td>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::select('hole'.$i.'_gir',[1 => 'Yes', 0 => 'No'],null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
</td>
@endfor
```

Comment: thank you. I could have sworn I did  it that way initially and it was just printing out &nbsp;.$1.&nbsp; when I viewed source. Works now. Thanks!!